# Excel VBA: Copy & Paste - Cells are being copied but not pasted

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am brand new to VBA and am working on writing some code that copies data from a column in one workbook and pastes the data into another.

See my code below:

```
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\RP\Desktop\CopyFrom.xlsm", True, True)

Dim startRow As Integer, endRow as Integer
With src.Sheets("Sheet1")
    startRow = .Range("B:B").Find(what:="*", after:=.Range("B1")).Row
    endRow = .Range("B:B").Find(what:="", after:=.Range("B1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With

src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & endRow).Copy
Sheets("PasteHere").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I have `startRow` and `startRow` since the data is in Column `B`but does not start in cell `B1`.

When I run the macro, I see that the data from the `src` file is copied (it has the dotted "ants" around it and I can paste it wherever I please). However, in my current workbook, there is no data pasted.

Can you help me figure this out? Thank you!

Comment: If you only need values, just set the `.Value` of the target range from the source range. You shouldn't need to copy and paste at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was commented you don't need to copy and paste if you just need the values; in fact copy and paste is much slower than working with the values directly!

```
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\RP\Desktop\CopyFrom.xlsm", True, True)
Set dest = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\RP\Desktop\CopyTo.xlsm", True, True)

Dim startRow As Integer, endRow as Integer
With src.Sheets("Sheet1")
    startRow = .Range("B:B").Find(what:="*", after:=.Range("B1")).Row
    endRow = .Range("B:B").Find(what:="", after:=.Range("B1"),      searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With

dest.Worksheets("PasteHere").Range("B1").Value = _ 
    src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
```

You can learn more about the Range object here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your answer! I initially did have it set up this way. However, nothing is copied into my current workbook. In fact, nothing is even copied to my clipboard. Do you have a clue into why this might be happening?

And thanks for the documentation - definitely helps me get a better understanding!

Comment: This way will not use your clipboard because it is not actually copying and pasting; it is taking a more direct approach

Comment: Right, but the cells in my PasteHere sheet are still blank.

Comment: @rrpking If your goal is to paste from one workbook into another workbook, you will need to make sure you specify those workbooks inside of Eric's answer; otherwise, you'll run into some issues with which workbook itself is active

Comment: Ah @RGA thank you! I was mind boggled as to why this wasn't working. Thanks again to both you and Eric

Comment: @Eric I'd recommend you edit your answer to include specifications to both workbooks so that the answer is more complete for others' future reference